# Rewrite htacess from https://example.com/folder/ to https://example.com/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I redirect from 
https://example.com/
to 
https://example.com/folder/

changing thehtacess file and using this code:

```
Redirect 301 ^$ https://example.com/folder/
```

now I would like to remove the subfolder when going on https://example.com/folder/. it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean, remove it? You just explicitly redirected there, what was the point of that then?

Comment: Do you actually want to serve the _content_ that is in `/ folder/`, but not have that show in the URL? So `https://example.com/foo` would serve the content of `/folder/foo`?  Then you don’t want an external redirect to begin with, you want an internal rewrite.